# Monolog's Pushover handler in Laravel 4 - Not working

Tags: php, push-notification, laravel-4, monolog

I am unable to use the Pushover handler of Monolog in Laravel4.

```
Route::get('test/log', function ()
{
    $monolog = Log::getMonolog();
    $monolog->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\PushoverHandler('XXX-my_api_key', 'xxx-my_user_key'));
    $monolog->info("yada ya da error");

    echo "Logged !";    
});
```

On running the route, I get a page with the "`logged !`" string.
When I checked the laravel.log file, I get

```
[2013-12-21 14:06:07] production.INFO: yada ya da error [] []
```

Comment: How is this a question, it sounds like everything worked... you shouldn't be doing echo in your routes but that's what would be the expected output otherwise. As for your logger, it logged it?

Comment: Yes, it logged to a file. I meant it to log to Pushover